# Run (Cygwin)C generated exe file using in Netbeans java with process

Tags: java, c, bash, netbeans

I have a c file called generator.c and by using cygwin64 i run make and generator.exe gets created

```
Bhulku-Parvat@DasNaDas /cygdrive/c/Users/Bhulku-Parvat/Desktop/bloom-filter
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ ./bloomgenerator.exe test 4 0.0003 'C:\Users\Bhulku-Parvat\Desktop' 'C:\Users\Bhulku-Parvat\Desktop\rawdata.txt'
```

and when i  run in cygwin i give 5 parameter ,it succesfully runs and generate desired ouput that is new file in specified loaction

Following is my Java Code

```java
public class Bloomtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p;
        System.out.println("----sart----");
        String cmmd[] = new String[3];

        try {
            cmmd[0] = "C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe";
            cmmd[1] = "-c";
            cmmd[2] = "'C:\\Users\\Bhulku-Parvat\\Desktop\\bloom-filter\\bloomgenerator.exe' 'testqw', '4', '0.0003', 'C:/Users/Bhulku-Parvat/Desktop' ,'C:/Users/Bhulku-Parvat/Desktop/rawdata.txt'";

            p = run.exec(cmmd);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(Bloomtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

**The problem is i want to run same command in java through netbeans using process or processbuilder but i am unable to run  help me out**

It gives the following output

> **/usr/bin/bash: C:\Users\Bhulku-Parvat\Desktop\bloom-filter\bloomgenerator.exe: command not found**

Comment: execute bloomgenerator.exe directly instead of bash.exe.

Comment: It gives following erro when running directly **java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "'C:\Users\Bhulku-Parvat\Desktop\bloom-filter\bloomgenerator.exe'": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**@Fildor